# Enable/disable input with radio input

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to enable an input when the radio is checked and then disable it when he's unchecked.

**HTML**

```
<input id="nam" class="col-md-4 form-check-input" type="radio" name="nam" checked="" data-waschecked="true" onclick="check()"> <
<input id="price" class="form-control" name="price" value="" disabled="disabled">
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="nam"]').click(function(){
        var $radio = $(this);

        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
        }
        else
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);

        $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
    });
});

function check() {
    var check = document.getElementById('nam').checked;
    if (check === true){
        document.getElementById('price').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else if (check === false){
        document.getElementById('price').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank in advance.

Comment: how might a user `uncheck` that radio button if they decided to?

Comment: Makes more sense to use a checkbox, no?! (At least if we're talking about only one set of elements ofc)

Comment: Are you aware you got an extra `<` after your first input element or is just a typo in the question?

Comment: Have you tried any of the two methods?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const toggleDisabled = (sel) => {
  const EL_target = document.querySelector(sel);
  EL_target.disabled = !EL_target.disabled;
};

const ELS_toggle = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle]");
ELS_toggle.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", function() {
  toggleDisabled(this.dataset.toggle);
}));
```

```html
<input data-toggle="#input-1" type="checkbox">
<input id="input-1" name="price" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<input id="price" class="form-control" name="price" disabled>
<input type ="checkbox" onchange = "document.querySelector('#price').disabled = !this.checked">
```